# Non Minimum Phase Systems and Sensor Location

Tags: sensor, stability

A stable minimum-phase system could potentially turn into a non-minimum-phase system after moving sensors to the AFT (behind) of the CG (Center of Gravity) of the vehicle [1](https://yilinmo.github.io/EE3011/Lec3.html). This is specifically applicable to conventional airplanes.

How sensor location can affect the minimum/non-minimum phase state of the system? In other words, how sensor's location can affect the presence of the RHP zeros in the system?

I understand that moving sensors does change the output of the system (C matrix) which will be reflected on location of zeros in S-Plane. But the part that I can not wrap my head around is the **mapping** from **sensor location** to **location of zeros** in the system.

From **Control System Design** by Karl Johan Åström, 2002 - Chapter 5:

> Problems that are caused by time delays and RHP zeros can be
> approached by moving sensors to different places. It can also be
> beneficial to add sensors.

Comment: The mapping will be non linear. Perhaps you can visualise it by drawing a root locus by gradually changing the sensor location and see how the zeroes move around between the half planes.

Comment: Rather than providing just a link, please include necessary details in the question itself. Currently by reading the question, it is not possible to know what the input is and what the output is and what the system being controlled is. The chances of getting a good answer will improve if the question is self contained. People are less likely to follow a link.

Comment: @AJN, this question does not concern the Input/Output or specifics of the the system. I added another quote to the original post from a well know control design reference which indicates my problems as a general statement.

Comment: Perhaps I have not understood the question clearly then. I still suggest the root locus method for general systems. Also see one of my [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/505289) which briefly touch on zeroes and input output selection.